# Doctrine2 : Applying a filter to an association

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

For example if I have :

```
class Parent {

/* ... */

/** One to Many association */
protected $children;

}

class Child
{
/* .. */
/** many to one association */
protected $parent;

/* name of child column */
protected $name;
}
```

Now, let's say for a parent, I want to filter the children by their name. If possible, somehow doing parent.getChildren() with this filter would be nice but that's impossible.

I'd like it to probably have the syntax getChildrenByName(), but this function seems unfitting for the ORM class and it's repository class. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't implementing `Parent::getChildren($name = null)´ work for you? Unless you're hydrating thousands of children and only a few of them match the criteria, there shouldn't be any reason to implement anything more complicated.

Answer (score 9):

This feature allows you to add criteria when fetching associations:

**Working With Associations: Filtering Collections**

- [Version 3.0](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)
- [Version 2.7](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)